# Throw error message in pre request script is not working

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

```
pm.sendRequest(options, function (err, res) {
    if (res.code == 400) {
        throw new Error("Invalid");
    }else{
        pm.request.headers.add({
        key: "Authorization",
        value: 'Bearer '+res.json().access_token});
    }
});
```

Above Pre Request Script is throwing Error

```
Response: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: Invalid
```

Postman Version: 9.7.1,
OS: Windows,
App Type: Postman Desktop Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does what it was asked , it throws the error “invalid” as the status was 400 .

so you get the mentioned error. saying “invalid” . Try changing the error message

Comment: How to ignore "Response: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:" in the Error Response. I need to print only `Error: Invalid`.

Comment: @Chand what you mean by ignore , what are you trying to do with that throw error statement.

Comment: if pre request script is failed, then with throw error statement I am stopping to send Main Request.